# Description of the x axis in R

Tags: r, plot, xlabs

I wrote a function in R to do hierarchical clustering.

```
Klasteryzacja_hierarchiczna = function(ExprSet,a,b,c,d) {
Klasteryzacja_h =exprs(ExprSet)'
clusters = hclust(dist(Klasteryzacja_h[a:b,c:d]))'
plot(clusters,xlab="Clusters")'
}
```

but it gave me this:

[image]
Do you know how to get rid of *hclust(*,"complete")*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `sub` parameter.

```
plot(clusters, xlab="Clusters", sub="")
```